# SvelteJS vs ReactJS rendering difference (repaint / reflow)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svelte, virtual-dom, svelte-3

Here's my naive understanding of how the DOM and browser works

Whenever something in the DOM ( the real dom ) changes the browser repaints or reflows that the DOM. So in simpler terms every time the DOM changes browser needs to recalculate the CSS, do a layout and repaint the web page. This is what takes time in real dom.

So React comes with this virtual DOM and what it actually does is it batches the changes and call applies them on real-dom in one go. Thus, minimizing the re-flow and re-paint.

Then what about Svelte. If it is manipulating the DOM directly how does it controls the repaint/reflow of the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the (correct) answer above: Svelte "compiles" the code that you provide to it, so the final code can be executed without a library runtime (in contrast to React). And it creates rather readable code, so it is absolutely possible to understand the inner workings.

Note: *This will be a bit longer answer - and still leave out many minute details about what is going on under the hood of Svelte. But I hope it helps to demystify some of the aspects what is going on under the hood. Also, this is how Svelte does things as of v3.16.x. Since this is internal, it might change. However, I still find it always rewarding to understand what is really going on.*

So, here we go.

**First and foremost:** The Svelte tutorial has a useful feature to let you see the generated code (right next to the "Result" pane). It might look a bit intimidating at first, but you quickly get the hang of it.

Below code will be based on this example (but further simplified): [Svelte tutorial - reactivity/assignments](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-assignments)

Our example component definition (i.e. *App.svelte*) looks like this:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>{count}</button>
```

Based on this component definition, the Svelte compiler creates a function which will create a "fragment" which receives and interacts with a "context".

```
function create_fragment(ctx) {
    let button;
    let t;
    let dispose;

    return {
        c() {
            button = element("button");
            t = text(/*count*/ ctx[0]);
            dispose = listen(button, "click", /*handleClick*/ ctx[1]);
        },
        m(target, anchor) {
            insert(target, button, anchor);
            append(button, t);
        },
        p(ctx, [dirty]) {
            if (dirty & /*count*/ 1) set_data(t, /*count*/ ctx[0]);
        },
        i: noop,
        o: noop,
        d(detaching) {
            if (detaching) detach(button);
            dispose();
        }
    };
}
```

The **fragment** is responsible to interact with the DOM and will be passed around with the component instance. In a nutshell, the code inside

- "c" will be run on **create** (creating the DOM elements in memory and also setting up the event handlers)
- "m" will run on **mount** (attaching the elements to the DOM)
- "p" will run on **update**, i.e. when something (including props) changes
- "i" / "o" are related to intro/outro (i.e. transitions)
- "d" will be run on **destroy**

Note: The functions like *element* or *set_data* are actually very approachable. 
For example, the function *element* is just a wrapper around *document.createElement*:

```
function element(name) {
    return document.createElement(name);
}
```

The **context** (ctx) will hold all instance variables as well as functions. It is nothing more than a simple array. Since Svelte "knows" what each index means at compile time, it can make hard references to the indices at other places.

This code essentially defines the instance context:

```
function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate) {
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        $$invalidate(0, count += 1);
    }

    return [count, handleClick];
}
```

Both the *instance* method as well as the *create_fragment* will be called from another function call *init*. It's a bit more involved, so instead of copy and pasting it here, you can have a look at this [link to the source](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/cd21acfb3cae574b81f2f417331993374222a9de/src/runtime/internal/Component.ts#L99).

The *$$invalidate* will make sure that the *count* variable is set as dirty and schedule an update. When the next update runs, it will look at all "dirty" components and update them. How this is happening is really more of an implementation detail. If interested, set a breakpoint in the [flush function](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/0bb40196db72c7166fa2a6e6715808d3bb2a83e3/src/runtime/internal/scheduler.ts#L34).

In fact, if you really want to go a bit deeper, I recommend to clone the [template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) app, then create a simple component, have it compiled and then inspect "bundle.js". You can also debug the actual code if you either delete the source maps or deactivate them.

So, for example set the rollup.config.js like so:

```
    output: {
        sourcemap: false,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            dev: false,
```

Note: As shown above, I recommend to also set *dev mode* to *false* since this will create more concise code.

*One neat feature:* Once our app is running, you can also access the *app* variable (it is assigned to the global window object since it is bundled as an immediately-invoked function expression).

So, you can open your console and simply say

```
console.dir(app)
```

which will produce something like this

```
App
    $$:  
        fragment: {c: ƒ, m: ƒ, p: ƒ, i: ƒ, o: ƒ, …}
        ctx: (2) [0, ƒ]
        props: {count: 0}
        update: ƒ noop()
        not_equal: ƒ safe_not_equal(a, b)
        bound: {}
        on_mount: []
        on_destroy: []
        before_update: []
        after_update: []
        context: Map(0) {}
        callbacks: {}
        dirty: [-1]
        __proto__: Object
    $set: $$props => {…}
```

One cool feature is that you can the *$set* method yourself to update the instance. For example like so:

```
app.$set({count: 10})
```

There are also [Svelte DevTools](https://github.com/RedHatter/svelte-devtools) which try to make the internals of Svelte more approachable. Somehow, they seemed to affect the render performance of my apps when I personally tried them out, so I don't use them myself. But certainly something to watch.

Well, there you have it. I know this is still rather technical, but I hope it helped to get a better understanding on what compiled Svelte code is doing.

Comment: Very detailed and understandable. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Both libraries minimize how many changes need to be made to the dom. The difference is the way that they figure out what that minimal set of changes is.

React's approach is to have a representation of the dom in memory (the virtual dom). When you set state, it runs the render process again to create another virtual dom. It compares the before and after, finds what changed, and then any changes get pushed to the real dom.

Svelte's approach is that when you set a variable, it sets a flag marking that variable as having changed. It knows which variables are dependent on other variables, so it then steps through any dependent variables and recalculates them, building up a list of what needs to change. Then these changes get pushed to the dom.

Comment: Yea I kind of get the gist of it. But I was expecting a little more behind the scenes and inner workings a bit more